# How to Subtract one day from system date in bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to subtract one day from system date in .bat file to append the date to my file.

Ex : if sysdate is 2023-07-14

i want to append the date to file : File_20230713.txt

Please help on this.

Comment: Use the `search` facility on the top line to find `[batch] yesterday` and your troubles will be far away...

Answer (score 0):

try this (save it like `.bat` file):

```
@if (@X) == (@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
    @echo off   
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
    exit /b %errorlevel%       
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var days=parseInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));


Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

var date = new Date();

WScript.Echo(date.addDays(5));
WScript.Echo("Year: " + date.getFullYear());
WScript.Echo("Month: " + date.getMonth());
WScript.Echo("DayOfTeWEek: " + date.getDay());
```

and use it like :

```
E:\scripts>dayAdder.bat -1
Sun Nov 8 16:27:48 UTC+0200 2020
Year: 2020
Month: 10
DayOfTeWEek: 2
DayOfTheMonth: 3
```

you can process the output with for loop or edit the output in jscript/batch polyglot.

Answer (score 0):

The following ideas, assume you are wanting to rename a file by replacing everything after, and including, the first `_`, *(if one exists)*, in the basename with the `_yyyyMMdd` suffix. If the basename doesn't have a `_` the suffix will just be appended to the existing name.

So for example

- `File.txt` -> `File_20230713.txt`
- `File_20230706.txt` -> `File_20230713.txt`

In both examples If you'd prefer to drag and drop your file onto the script, or pass it as an argument via the command line, you would simply replace the example filename `"File.txt"`, on lines **3.** and **4.** respectively, with `"%~1"`.

---

You could get the assistance of [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) in your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), *(although slower than using [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript))*.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Call :AddDateSuffix "File.txt"
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:AddDateSuffix
For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
 -NoProfile "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyMMdd')"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=_" %%H In ("%~n1") Do Echo=Ren "%~1" "%%~nH_%%G%~x1"
Exit /B
```

If you're satisfied with the output, remove `Echo=` from line **10.**, to actually perform the rename, and optionally line **4.**, `Pause`.

---

You could if you want something a little faster get the help of [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) via [wsh](/questions/tagged/wsh) instead:

```bash
<!-- :
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Call :AddDateSuffix "File.txt"
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:AddDateSuffix
For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=_" %%H In ("%~n1") Do Echo=Ren "%~1" "%%~nH_%%G%~x1"
Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
    dtmYesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Now())
    strDate = Year(dtmYesterday) _
      & Right("0" & Month(dtmYesterday), 2) _
      & Right("0" & Day(dtmYesterday), 2)
    WScript.Echo strDate
  </Script></Job>
```

If you're satisfied with the output, remove `Echo=` from line **10.**, to actually perform the rename, and optionally line **5.**, `Pause`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use powershell, or jscript, or vbscript, or wsh, or other more complicated and less efficient methods to solve this problem. However, if you want to make it in [a *very simple* way](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9047), you could get the result in a pure Batch file via *a single `set /A` command*:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Assume that %date% variable have the date in YYYY-MM-DD format, like "2023-07-14" (as requested)
rem otherwise, just rearrange the %%a, %%b and %%c variables (and use other "delims", like "/")

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ("%date%") do set /A "YYYY=%%a, M=1%%b-100, D=1%%c-100"
set /A "C1=^!(D-=1),MM=100+(M-=C1*(1-12*(C2=^!(M-1)))),YYYY-=C1*C2,DD=100+(D+=C1*(30+((M+(M>>3))&1)-^!(M-2)*(2-^!(YYYY%%4))))"
echo Filename: File_%YYYY%%MM:~1%%DD:~1%.txt
```